# Grouping the data in SAS into specific buckets

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I need some help to satisfy the below requirement

Currentdataset (dataset name: SAS1):

```
product_no product_type status1 status2
12345      3            x       0
12345      1            x       1
123456     3            x       1
123456     6            x       0
9876       3            x+1     0
9876       1            x+1     0
```

So basically, in the above dataset, if `status2=1 and status1='x' and product_type<>3`, then for both the rows, the `status1` should be `'nr'`. if `status2=1 and status1='x' and product_type=3`, then for both the rows, the `status1` should be `'x+1'`. if `status2=0 and status1='x+1'`, then for both the rows, the `status1` should be `'x+1'`

Desired Output (datasetname: SAS2):

```
product_no product_type status1 status2
12345      3            nr      0
12345      1            nr      1
123456     3            x+1     1
123456     6            x+1     0
9876       3            x+1     0
9876       1            x+1     0
```

CODE TRIED, BUT IT DIDN'T WORK:

```
proc sql;create table sas2 as 
select 
    a.*,
    case
    when status2=0 and status1='x+1' then 'x+1'
    WHEN status2=1 and  status1='x' and product_type=3 then 'nr'
    WHEN status2=1 and  status1='x'  and product_type ne 3 then 'x+1'
    WHEN status2=1 and  status1='NotActive' then 4
END AS status3 FROM sas1 AS a;quit;
```

The above code doesn't work. So for example, for product_no=12345, the condition is only satisfied for that particular row, not for the whole group. So for product_no=12345, the column status1='nr' should be populated for both rows, not just the one.

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: @user667489 I added the code that I tried to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you will need some grouping in order to apply the computed value to 'two' rows.  From the sample data the only two row group would be based on `product_no`.  A summation of a logical evaluation over the group will tell you if any of the rows in the group meet the criteria.  `Proc SQL` queries will also do automatic remerging when non-aggregate selection are made whilst a `group by` clause is specified.  The case statement will compute the `status1` value based on the first occurring when condition of the case statement

Example:

```
data have;input
product_no product_type status1 $ status2 ; datalines;
12345      3            x       0
12345      1            x       1
123456     3            x       1
123456     6            x       0
9876       3            x+1     0
9876       1            x+1     0
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    product_no
  , product_type
  , case 
      when sum(status2=1 and status1='x' and product_type ne 3) > 0 then 'nr'
      when sum(status2=1 and status1='x' and product_type eq 3) > 0 then 'x+1'
      when sum(status2=0 and status1='x+1') > 0 then 'x+1'
      else status1
    end as status1
  , status2
  from have
  group by product_no
  ;
```